# A repeated visitation to a certain url of my app. Why?

Tags: attacks

My app is hosted on google app engine.

I just realise there is a regular visitation from a single IP address to a particular url of my app.

[image]

My app always returns 500 because of this runtime error. It is most likely the requests are made by a script (because the user agent column shows 'Unknown')

[image]

The incoming IP address is resolved to a physical location in Atlanta, Georgia, USA.

Anyone know why these GET requests happen? Can they be considered 'attacks'? They look rather benign to me.

**Edit:**

The get request:

[image]

Comment: The GET request is to a very common subfolder location. It looks like a scan looking for common locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the IP address of the requestor belongs to "Rocket Science Group, LLC". Upon visiting their website, it looks like they develop applications as well. Now knowing who the requester is, does this shed some light on what the activity could be and if it is wanted? Here is a link to their website: http://rocketsciencegroup.com/

Comment: Interesting! I do use some of their services e.g. mandrill. Thanks a lot!